# Weird pdfs from Generalised Extreme Value (GEV) Maximum Likelihood fitted data

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I am doing some data analysis involving fitting datasets to a Generalised Extreme Value (GEV) distribution, but I'm getting some weird results.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev
import numpy
data = [1.47, 0.02, 0.3, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.12, 0.38, 0.02, 0.15, 0.01, 0.3, 0.24, 0.01, 0.05, 0.01, 0.0, 0.06, 0.01, 0.01, 0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.09, 0.03, 0.22, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]
x = numpy.linspace(0, 2, 20)
pdf = gev.pdf(x, *gev.fit(data))
print(pdf)
```

And the output:

```
array([  5.64759709e+05,   2.41090345e+00,   1.16591714e+00,
         7.60085002e-01,   5.60415578e-01,   4.42145248e-01,
         3.64144425e-01,   3.08947114e-01,   2.67889183e-01,
         2.36190826e-01,   2.11002185e-01,   1.90520108e-01,
         1.73548832e-01,   1.59264573e-01,   1.47081601e-01,
         1.36572220e-01,   1.27416958e-01,   1.19372442e-01,
         1.12250072e-01,   1.05901466e-01,   1.00208313e-01,
         9.50751375e-02,   9.04240603e-02,   8.61909342e-02,
         8.23224528e-02,   7.87739599e-02,   7.55077677e-02,
         7.24918532e-02,   6.96988348e-02,   6.71051638e-02,
         6.46904782e-02,   6.24370827e-02,   6.03295277e-02,
         5.83542648e-02,   5.64993643e-02,   5.47542808e-02,
         5.31096590e-02,   5.15571710e-02,   5.00893793e-02,
         4.86996213e-02,   4.73819114e-02,   4.61308575e-02,
         4.49415891e-02,   4.38096962e-02,   4.27311763e-02,
         4.17023886e-02,   4.07200140e-02,   3.97810205e-02,
         3.88826331e-02,   3.80223072e-02])
```

The problem is that the first value is huge, totally distorting all the results, its show quite clearly in a plot:
[image: pdf]

I've experimented with other data, and random samples, and in some cases it works.  The first value in my dataset is significantly higher than the rest, but it is a valid value so I can't just drop it.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

**Update**

Here is another example showing the problem much more clearly:

```
In [1]: from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev, kstest

In [2]: data = [0.01, 0.0, 0.28, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.13, 0.07, 0.03
, 0.01, 0.42, 0.11, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.26, 1.32, 0.06, 0.02,
1.57, 0.07, 1.56, 0.04]

In [3]: fit = gev.fit(data)

In [4]: kstest(data, 'genextreme', fit)
Out[4]: (0.48015007915450658, 6.966510064376763e-07)

In [5]: x = linspace(0, 2, 200)

In [6]: plot(x, gev.pdf(x, *fit))
Out[6]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x97590f0>]

In [7]: hist(data)
```

Note specifically, line 4 shows a p-value of about 7e-7, way below what's normally considered acceptable.  Here is the plot produced:

[image: 2nd Figure]

Comment: You seem to be missing a parentheses at the end of `pdf = gev.pdf(x, *gev.fit(data)`. Once I fix that, I get different output to you: the first few array elements are `[0.86052504 1.26941931 1.87260719 2.76241087 ...]` and the rest all zero.

Comment: @sjy That was just a copy/paste error.  However, your results look far better than mine. What version of scipy are you using?

Comment: `0.11.0` according to `scipy.version.version`. I don't remember installing it, I think this is just what comes with OS X?

Comment: I'm on 0.13.3, so maybe that's got something to do with it.  No idea what though...

Comment: @aquavitae, I have your same results, OSx with scipy 0.13.3. If you try fitting `gumbel_r`, that is some sort of subcase of GEV, you have a decent fit. If you try fitting `frechet_r` however, the fit is even worse on my machine with `data[0]=2.6e16`. Are you sure your data can be modelled by a GEV? Could you use a Gumbel instead?

Comment: @flebool GEV is the right model, its hydrological data (specifically max annual river flows).  I suppose the question is whether its a bug in scipy or whether there is a limitation to the fitting model that manifests in this particular dataset.

Comment: @aquavitae, see edit. A side note on KS test. You are testing the goodness-of-fit to a GEV with its parameter ESTIMATED FROM THE DATA itself. In such a case, the p value is invalid, see: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm, `3. Perhaps the most serious limitation...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I think you may want to keep you location parameter fixed at `0`.

Second, you got zeros in your data, the resulting fit may have `+inf` `pdf` at `x=0` e.g. for the GEV fit or for the Weibull fit.
Therefore, the fit is actually correct, but when you plot the `pdf` (including `x=0`), the resulting plot is distorted.

Third, I really think `scipy` should drop the support for `x=0` for a bunch of distributions such as `Weibull`. For `x=0`, `R` gives a nice warning of `Error in fitdistr(data, "weibull") : Weibull values must be > 0`, that is helpful.

```
In [103]:

p=ss.genextreme.fit(data, floc=0)
ss.genextreme.fit(data, floc=0)
Out[103]:
(-1.372872096699608, 0, 0.011680600795499299)
In [104]:

plt.hist(data, bins=20, normed=True, alpha=0.7, label='Data')
plt.plot(np.linspace(5e-3, 1.6, 100),
         ss.genextreme.pdf(np.linspace(5e-3, 1.6, 100), p[0], p[1], p[2]), 'r--',
         label='GEV Fit')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.savefig('T1.png')
```

[image]

```
In [105]:

p=ss.expon.fit(data, floc=0)
ss.expon.fit(data, floc=0)
Out[105]:
(0, 0.14838807003769505)
In [106]:

plt.hist(data, bins=20, normed=True, alpha=0.7, label='Data')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1.6, 100),
         ss.expon.pdf(np.linspace(0, 1.6, 100), p[0], p[1]), 'r--',
         label='Expon. Fit')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.savefig('T2.png')
```

[image]

```
In [107]:

p=ss.weibull_min.fit(data[data!=0], floc=0)
ss.weibull_min.fit(data[data!=0], floc=0)
Out[107]:
(0.67366030738733995, 0, 0.10535422201164378)
In [108]:

plt.hist(data[data!=0], bins=20, normed=True, alpha=0.7, label='Data')
plt.plot(np.linspace(5e-3, 1.6, 100),
         ss.weibull_min.pdf(np.linspace(5e-3, 1.6, 100), p[0], p[1], p[2]), 'r--',
         label='Weibull_Min Fit')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.savefig('T3.png')
```

[image]

---

## edit

Your second data (which contains even more `0`'s )is a good example when MLE fit involving location parameter can become very challenging, especially potentially with a lot of float point overflow/underflow involved:

```
In [122]:
#fit with location parameter fixed, scanning loc parameter from 1e-8 to 1e1
L=[] #stores the Log-likelihood
P=[] #stores the p value of K-S test
for LC in np.linspace(-8, 1, 200):
    fit = gev.fit(data, floc=10**LC)
    L.append(np.log(gev.pdf(data, *fit)).sum())
    P.append(kstest(data, 'genextreme', fit)[1])
L=np.array(L)
P=np.array(P)
In [123]:
#plot log likelihood, a lot of overflow/underflow issues! (see the zigzag line?)
plt.plot(np.linspace(-8, 1, 200), L,'-')
plt.ylabel('Log-Likelihood')
plt.xlabel('$log_{10}($'+'location parameter'+'$)$')
```

[image]

```
In [124]:
#plot p-value
plt.plot(np.linspace(-8, 1, 200), np.log10(P),'-')
plt.ylabel('$log_{10}($'+'K-S test P value'+'$)$')
plt.xlabel('$log_{10}($'+'location parameter'+'$)$')
Out[124]:
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x107e3050>
```

[image]

```
In [128]:
#The best fit between with location paramter between 1e-8 to 1e1 has the loglikelihood of 515.18
np.linspace(-8, 1, 200)[L.argmax()]
fit = gev.fit(data, floc=10**(np.linspace(-8, 1, 200)[L.argmax()]))
np.log(gev.pdf(data, *fit)).sum()
Out[128]:
515.17663678368604
In [129]:
#The simple MLE fit is clearly bad, loglikelihood is -inf
fit0 = gev.fit(data)
np.log(gev.pdf(data, *fit0)).sum()
Out[129]:
-inf

In [133]:
#plot the fit
x = np.linspace(0.005, 2, 200)
plt.plot(x, gev.pdf(x, *fit))
plt.hist(data,normed=True, alpha=0.6, bins=20)
Out[133]:
(array([ 8.91719745,  0.8492569 ,  0.        ,  1.27388535,  0.        ,
        0.42462845,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.42462845,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.8492569 ]),
 array([ 0.    ,  0.0785,  0.157 ,  0.2355,  0.314 ,  0.3925,  0.471 ,
        0.5495,  0.628 ,  0.7065,  0.785 ,  0.8635,  0.942 ,  1.0205,
        1.099 ,  1.1775,  1.256 ,  1.3345,  1.413 ,  1.4915,  1.57  ]),
 <a list of 20 Patch objects>)
```

[image]

---

## Edit, goodness of fit test for GEV

A side note on KS test. You are testing the goodness-of-fit to a GEV with its parameter ESTIMATED FROM THE DATA itself. In such a case, the p value is invalid, see: itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm

There seems to be a lot of studies on the topic of goodness-of-fit test for GEV, I haven't found any available implementations for those yet.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/98WR02364/abstract
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/91WR00077/abstract
[http://www.idrologia.polito.it/~laio/articoli/16-WRR%20EDFtest.pdf](http://www.idrologia.polito.it/%7Elaio/articoli/16-WRR%20EDFtest.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. However this doesn't really solve the problem. I am analysing several million datasets like this, so I can't check things manually for each one. Also, using `kstest` to calculate p-values, I'm getting about 35% unacceptable fits, i.e. p << 0.01. When I'm back at my computer I'll update my question with some more specific data illustrating this.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! So if the log-likelihood/loc is that varied, how can I determine it?  The only way I see is to do exactly what you did, i,e, calculate it for a range of `loc` and find the max.  Or is there a quicker way?  Also, if `kstest` is not suitable, then what method would be ok?  I just really need some measure of how close the data matches the calculated fit in order to identify cases like this.

Comment: I think, for some dataset like the 2nd one, it is numerically difficult to find the MLE. It takes some trickery to find the MLE (like in this case, we scan over a region for the loc parameter). I'll suggest to try some of the related `R` packages for GEV (a nice list of them can be found at http://www.ral.ucar.edu/~ericg/softextreme.php) and see if their method is more robust. Also I wouldn't be surprised if those `R` packages are faster than `scipy.stats`. See edit for your second question.