# Method of moments in scipy?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

Following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167975/weird-pdfs-from-fitted-data), is there a way to use any method other than MLE (maximum-likelihood estimation) for fitting a continuous distribution in scipy?  I think that my data may be resulting in the MLE method diverging, so I want to try using the method of moments instead, but I can't find out how to do it in scipy.  Specifically, I'm expecting to find something like

```
scipy.stats.genextreme.fit(data, method=method_of_moments)
```

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how to do it?

Comment: Not in scipy stats, not out of the box anyway. You're probably better off with DIY. If you give more details on the math involved, it'll be easier to say something useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things to mention:

1) `scipy` does not have support for GMM. There is some support for GMM via `statsmodels` (http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/gmm.html), you can also access many R routines via `Rpy2` (and `R` is bound to have every flavour of GMM ever invented): http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/index.html

2) Regarding stability of convergence, if this is the issue, then probably your problem is not with the objective being maximised (eg. likelihood, as opposed to a generalised moment) but with the optimiser. Gradient optimisers can be really fussy (or rather, the problems we give them are not really suited for gradient optimisation, leading to poor convergence).

If statsmodels and Rpy do not give you the routine you need, it is perhaps a good idea to write out your moment computation out verbose, and see how you can maximise it yourself - perhaps a custom-made little tool would work well for you?